# Should I use Flutter Web for a website project that shall go into production not before summer?

Tags: django, flutter, flutter-web

## TL;DR

Is it smart to have a website that shall go into production ~July be developed with Flutter for Web considering Flutter-based mobile apps may follow 2021?

## Preface:

I am planning website project and will start looking for a developer this week to build an MVP. I know I want Django for the backend, but frontend-wise I am not so sure.

Its my first larger website project and I am not really familiar with different frontend technologies.

I guess I need to trade off between cheaper implementation of an MVP that I need to check if the idea could finance itself and something that is more expensice upfront that could last longer.

In the long run, if the MVP is successful, I could imagine having native web as well. Flutter seems to be a very interesting framework to minimize development cost. However, initially it will be web only and Flutter is only in beta phase there.

The options I see are:

- Django backend and frontend (maybe with some Angular/React/Vue directly inside the Django Templates)
- Django backend + Django REST Framework + Angular/React/Vue frontend
- Django backend + Django REST Framework + Flutter Frontend (hoping it will be stable enough by summer)

## Actual Questions:

- Can asking a developer to build a website now that shall go into
  production in summer (i. e. it doesn't have to work perfectly fine
  immediately, July or so would be enough) with flutter as frontend
  really be an option?
- Is it likely at all Flutter for Web will become
  stable enough by then?
- What would be the effort to transfer a
  Angular/React/Vue website to a flutter website later on?
- Will looking for a Flutter Web developer who also can do Django limit me too much?
  (i. e. it seems to me most developers know either Angular/React/Vue
  but much fewer know Flutter, let alone Flutter Web)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I am eligible to answer this question as I am currently working on these techs (Flutter, Django, Angular, etc.). So I am assuming you want to start the development in the next two weeks. 
My One-Line suggestion would be not to go with Flutter until your first priority is a mobile app. 
There is still uncertainty about the stable release of Flutter Web and it's not confirmed if the Flutter team is going to release the stable release of Flutter Web by next year's summer. I have done POC with it and still find it unstable for production release as it has many issues. Flutter's official website itself does not suggest you deploy it in production for the web. You can read it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web#is-the-web-version-of-flutter-ready-for-production) 
If any developer starts development with Flutter for a website now, the developer can face many issues in the development and may not find some features which you want the website to have. So it's not mature enough right now to develop a website for production.
If you want an app then you can go with Flutter without any second thought. Many companies and startups are using it for production. You can check [here](https://flutter.dev/showcase)

So it's very unlikely to be production-ready for Flutter-Web by July'21. You can check the milestones for Flutter [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/milestones) and I think it will take 0.5 to 1 year after the stable release of Flutter to be production-ready for the web.

To answer your third question, I need to know the complexity of the website. Probably you can start with [AngularDart](https://angulardart.dev/) and it can reduce migration efforts in the future.

Comment: Thanks snj, that was extremely helpful. I will go with something other than Flutter for the beginning then ;)

Comment: and for a windows desktop app ?

Comment: The final UI of Flutter is very promising but you should not expect it to be production-ready within the next 6 months for sure.

Comment: thank you for that detailed feedback. is this answer still up to date in jan 2021?

Comment: As of 2021-07-31, Flutter Web does not feel mature. Many issues. Crashes, weird behaviors, hot reload failures, debugging issues (debugger doesn't always work correctly and is plagued by various issues). To me it feels like somewhere between Alpha and Beta quality.

Comment: As of 2022-02-10 Flutter web definitely works fine for building stable web applications. The only thing missing for me is a 3D charting / modelling option which is currently not possible but if you have no need for that Flutter is now a fine choice for building web apps. Also check https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web for the official documentation on Flutter for web and best scenarios.